# How to get different mathematical Greek symbols psi and varphi?

Tags: greek

[image: Please see the picture] How do I change from the first `psi` and `varphi` symbols to the second symbols on Overleaf ? Please see the picture. Which package or font will get me the second symbols ?

---

Edit: on using `\usepackage{stix2}` I am getting a lot of errors

These were the other packages present in the template beforehand

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{appendix}
```

The following are the top three errors

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty, line 241

LaTeX Error: 

Command \refeq already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

 ...                                                                                                
l.241 }

 /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2/stix2.sty, line 87

LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.                                 
                                                  
l.87 ...nt{arrows1}       {LS1}{stix2sf}   {m} {n}

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2/stix2.sty, line 88

LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.

l.88 ...nt{arrows2}       {LS1}{stix2sf}   {m}{it}
```

Comment: Those are the same symbol in different fonts, I think...

Comment: @Rmano, please see the edited question, yes I need the package/font.

Comment: Guessing a font by just the shape is quite complex. If you have a PDF document with the shapes you want, you can analyze it and see if you can find the font name (in unix `pdffonts` will help). Or you can spend a bit of time (or a lot of it) browsing [the LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/)

Comment: Could it be https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/stix2/?

Comment: They aren't different *symbols*, but just different *renderings* of the same symbols. Nobody should rely on a particular rendering to convey a meaning.

Comment: Excuse me. Do you have taken, please, your image?

Comment: @Sebastiano, sorry what does your question mean ?

Comment: OK, so the author of the text for the second group of symbols told me, it is one of these three font types - UCP-Maths-Symbol, MinionPro-Regular (OpenType), and STIXGeneral-Regular (TrueType). So how do I get them and use them on Overleaf ? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: @Rmano please see my last comment

Comment: @Sebastiano, please see my last comment

Comment: @egreg, please see my last comment

Comment: As I suggested above, `\usepackage{stix2}`... I think that the other fonts you mention are commercial (non-free)

Comment: I got hundreds of errors when I added `\usepackage{stix2}` :(

Comment: no one can debug "I got hundreds of errors" if you get an error post a new question with a small but complete example and show the exact error that you got (usually only the first error is important)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see the top three error messages. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `times` package defines many of the same symbols as `stix2`; Start by commenting it out.